# Connecting SQL Server in a Docker image from SSMS (Win 10) throws an error 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the host'

Tags: sql-server, docker

The environment is a single machine trying to connect to SQL Server 2019 in a Docker image (`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`). The first time I tried this was with this tutorial:
[tomssl](https://tomssl.com/running-microsoft-sql-server-on-a-linux-container-in-docker/) and the connection using SSMS worked. But I need SQL Server 2019, so I tried the 2019-latest image, and the connection closed issue is now permanent.

[image: Cannot connect forcibly closed]

If I remove the port number then the password error appears.

The docker image:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU8-ubuntu-16.04
```

The run command from docker:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Simp$on9432' -p 1405:1433 --name sql19-25 -v D:\Docker:/sql -d  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU8-ubuntu-16.04 sleep infinity
```

The `sleep infinity` was added to keep the image running.

I have tried to do the 2017 version again, but the same error appears.

The command was run in PowerShell 7.1.0.

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.19042 Build 19042

Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3

WSL 2 installed

Storage Driver: overlay2

Through SSMS (v18.8), I can connect to `SQLEXPRESS`. Also I have tried stopping the `SQLEXPRESS`, but still get the same error message.

Suggestions?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: No, I have switched over to Postgres. Thanks for asking.